# Got Error while build angular app Expected an expression, but saw AST

Tags: angular

I worked good first but suddenly it shows the following error while building the app :-

```
ERROR in : Error: Expected an expression, but saw AST
    at ensureExpressionMode (E:\xampp\htdocs\example\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:7182:19)
    at _AstToIrVisitor.visitImplicitReceiver (E:\xampp\htdocs\example\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:7304:13)
    at ImplicitReceiver.visit (E:\xampp\htdocs\example\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:6289:28)
    at convertActionBinding (E:\xampp\htdocs\example\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:7095:49)
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\example\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:22304:26
    at Array.forEach ()
    at ViewBuilder._createElementHandleEventFn (E:\xampp\htdocs\example\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:22300:22)
    at nodes.(anonymous function) (E:\xampp\htdocs\example\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:21898:27)
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\example\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:22262:26
    at Array.map ()
    at ViewBuilder._createNodeExpressions (E:\xampp\htdocs\example\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:22261:43)
    at ViewBuilder.build (E:\xampp\htdocs\example\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:21733:27)
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\example\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:21732:67
    at Array.forEach ()
    at ViewBuilder.build (E:\xampp\htdocs\example\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:21732:27)
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\example\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:21732:67
```

**Angular Version:**

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.9                                                 
Node: 10.15.0                                                      
OS: win32 x64                                                      
Angular: 7.2.15                                                    
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms        
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic   
... router                                                         

Package                           Version                          
-----------------------------------------------------------        
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.9                           
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.9                           
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.9                           
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.9                           
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.9                            
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.9                            
@angular/cli                      7.3.9                            
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.9                            
@schematics/angular               7.3.9                            
@schematics/update                0.13.9                           
rxjs                              6.3.3                            
typescript                        3.2.4                            
webpack                           4.29.0
```

Comment: You have some error in one of your templates with an action binding `(click)=""`

Comment: Is there any way to find which template cause this issue or i need to check one by  one

Comment: load the sourcemaps (which it should by default), put a breakpoint on `ensureExpressionMode` in the angular code, perhaps you'll get a bigger stack trace, or any values inside the debugger will give you a clue

Comment: Solved! thanks! one of template issue

Comment: Alright, perhaps you could write an answer here with your wrong code. Could help future readers :)